# Positioning scrolling divs

Tags: html, css

I come to you once more for a question. I've got a logo consisting of three elements:  TEXT | LOGO | TEXT. The logo part is static. It should always be horizontal + vertical centered. I've accomplished this with a background. The two text parts need to be able to scroll up and down and when it leaves the top of the page a new version should come up from the bottom of the page and stop at the point that it's exactly lined up with the logo again.

I've got this perfectly working on my own desktop which is a 1920 * 1080 resolution. However, i've done this trough padding and pixels.

```
#logo {
background:none;
padding-top:411px;
}
#logo2 {
background:none;
padding-top:958px;
}
#logo3 {
background:none;
padding-top:962px;
}
```

Obviously this is not the way to go since on any other resolution the alignment is totally off.

I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thedonny/mzr91b4f/

Since the Fiddle shows the output in a smaller screen you already see my problem. I pretty sure im missing something here. Is there anyone that could point me in a right direction on how to pull this of?

Kind regards,
Arjen.

Comment: I am not sure this can be done in pure css. I might be wrong, but it looks like you might want to look at $(window).height(); and $(window).scroll(); => window.pageYOffset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/mzr91b4f/2/

I made each of the `#section`s 100% the height of the viewport (after setting `html`, `body`, and `.container-fluid` to 100% height). I then made each of the `#logo`s offset from the top by 50% with a margin-top of (approximately) half the height of the image. I did some funky adjustment to the last `#logo` to get it to be exactly the height of the viewport so the scrollbar stops exactly at the bottom of the window on Section Three. Here is the CSS (a bit reorganized):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5rFLWpS.png) repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sectionone, #sectiontwo, #sectionthree {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#logo {
    background:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -72px;
}
#logo2 {
    background:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
    margin-top: -72px;
}
#logo3 {
    background:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250%;
    margin-top: -72px;
    bottom: 300%;
    margin-bottom: -72px;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I actualy was fooling around with percentages, however only on the child element. Didn't think of setting the parent elements. Thank you a bunch! Realy great!